# Google Authenticator signed out of my account. I can't sign back in without a PIN I have never created. Where do I go to create or reset this PIN?

Tags: google-authenticator

Google Authenticator has (not for the first time!) decided to forget all my codes and sign me out.

However, this time when I tap Sign In I an prompted to 'Confirm your PIN':
[image]

I have never set this PIN. Where do I find it in my Google Account settings? Preferably, how do I disable the PIN entirely and revert to using my account username/password pair?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. I have been using Google Authenticator app for years and I don't recognize this look. Is this [the official Google Authenticator app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2)? Otherwise, could you mention the device model and whether there's a parental control/app lock/device administrator active?

Comment: @AndrewT. It's the official Google Authenticator app (Version 6.0) running on a Huawei PLE-701L, not rooted/jailbroken or anything like that. There are no parental controls or app locks - I am the sole user of the device.

Comment: Based on a quick research, looks like this is the same screen for unlocking the device on Huawei. This is because apps can request Android to show the "lock screen" to authenticate the user.

Comment: @AndrewT. You should make that an answer

Comment: @AndrewT. This is not the same screen that unlocks the device - that looks like a standard Android unlock screen and nothing like this - but the device unlock PIN is what it was asking for and that's what worked! I have never seen an app use this interface before, nor have I ever had an app ask for my device unlock PIN to do anything so it never occurred to me that was the PIN I should use. In the small chance anyone from Google ever sees this: This is absolutely terrible UX! Nevertheless, if you can turn your comment into an answer I can accept it. :) Thanks for your help!